# Solve $\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{6}e^{x}}{\left ( e^{x}-1 \right )^{2}}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Solve
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{6}e^{x}}{\left ( e^{x}-1 \right )^{2}}dx$$
I tried integration by part to get
$$I=6\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{5}}{e^{x}-1}dx$$
But I stuck here.How can I go further after this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n>1$ we have
$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\frac{x^{n-1}}{e^{x}-1}\, \mathrm{d}x=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\int_{0}^{\infty }x^{n-1}e^{-kx}\, \mathrm{d}x\overset{[1]}{=}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty }\frac{1}{k^{n}}\int_{0}^{\infty }x^{n-1}e^{-x}\, \mathrm{d}x=\zeta \left ( n \right )\Gamma \left ( n \right )$$
where $\zeta(\cdot)$ is [Riemann zeta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) and $\Gamma(\cdot)$ is [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

$[1]:$ Let $kx\to x$

Hence let $n=6$ we obtain the answer
$$I=\frac{16}{21}\pi ^{6}$$